# Detecting Bluetooth Keyboard in iPad App

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, bluetooth, eaaccessory

In my app I am having a customer info form on which there are a number of text fields I have used, now when a user edits any field I need to move whole view up so that the editing text field won't get under iPad's internal keyboard and this is working fine.
Now the client wants to use external Bluetooth keyboard for filling this form. Once this external keyboard is connected with iPad then in the app when editing any text field won't show internal keyboard as the external is connected and in this case whole view needs to be on the page and no need to move it up.
But when I edit text field it still goes up without showing internal keyboard on the screen and this leaves half of the screen blank as it moves whole view up.

For this I have tried some ways like enabling internal keyboard show/hide notifications but these notification only gets called when external keyboard is not connected and this is not helping me.
Also have tried with ExternalAccessory framework, but it wont detect the bluetooth connected keyboard also tried with EADemo to detect external keyboard and its not detecting external keyboard but it detects credit card swiper connected trough dock.

If anyone here has gone through this functionality or knows anything related with this, then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

@SpySudhir --

Logic A:

- have a bool variable in some file which will return yes/no value when the keyboard is external or internal.
- On the basis of the bool value returned call the animation function.

Logic B:

- Listen to the keyboard notification using NSNotificationCenter.
- Notifications like will,show,hide notification put an NSLog over their and see which one of them is getting called.
- If external board is connected the willShow method does not gets called. so in this case can we can do some work around and set the bool value to no or we can have a counter and check it every time if its value is increased by one or is same something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You should not move the view up when field gets focus - you should only move the view up as a response to a UIKeyboardDidShowNotification. The system takes care of the rest for you.